# Remove entire column if one or more rows contains 0 in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction/version/1#kc_house_data.csv
and I need to remove columns that with one or more rows that contains "0" but I can't, I tried a few ideas that I found here but none of them works for me, someone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```r
df[apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) all(x != 0)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach

```
library(dplyr)

select_if(data, ~{!0 %in% unique(.)})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use vectorized option with `rowSums`  from `base R` to remove the rows having any 0

```
df[!rowSums(!df),, drop  = FALSE]
#  v1 v2 v3
#3  2  1  2
```

Or using `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(df, `!=`, 0)),, drop = FALSE]
#   v1 v2 v3
#3  2  1  2
```

Or with `filter_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter_all(all_vars(. != 0))
#   v1 v2 v3
#1  2  1  2
```

---

If it is to remove columns, use `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) !any(x ==0), df2)
#  v2
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
```

Or with `sapply`

```
df2[sapply(df2,  function(x) all(x != 0))]
#  v2
#1  1
#2  2
#3  3
```

#### data

```
 df <- data.frame(v1 = c(0, 1, 2), v2 = c(1, 0, 1), v3 = c(0, 1, 2))
 df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c(0, 1, 2), v2 = c(1, 2, 3), v3 = c(1, 0, 3))
```